# Python MYSQL multiple statement execution issue

Tags: python, mysql, sql

Suppose I have this multiple-process Python-MySql query:

```
self.calculateLeadTime = ("""SET @lastDate = (SELECT sessionDate FROM stock 
WHERE product = (%s)
ORDER BY stocksessionID DESC LIMIT 1);

SET @secondLastDate = (SELECT sessionDate FROM stock WHERE product = (%s)
ORDER BY stocksessionID DESC LIMIT 1, 1);

SET @leadTime = (SELECT DATEDIFF(@lastDate, @secondLastDate));
SET @lastStockSessionID = (SELECT stocksessionID
FROM stock WHERE product = (%s) ORDER BY stocksessionID DESC LIMIT 1);

UPDATE stock SET leadTime = (@leadTime)
WHERE stocksessionID = @lastStockSessionID;""", (self.productID.get(), self.productID.get(), self.productID.get()))

self.query = self.cur.execute(self.calculateLeadTime, multi=True)
for self.cur in self.results:
     print('cursor:', self.cur)
     if self.cur.with_rows:
         print('result:', self.cur.fetchall())
self.cn.commit()
```

I am subject to the error:

> stmt = operation.encode(self._connection.python_charset)
>       AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'encode'

I have read the MySql Python documentation regarding `multi=True` when executing multiple SQL statements via Python. However, my implementation does not work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, you are passing a tuple as first argument in the [`cursor.execute`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html) call when it expects a single scalar query string in first argument and tuple/list of parameters in second argument:

```
self.calculateLeadTime = """SET @lastDate = (SELECT sessionDate 
                                             FROM stock 
                                             WHERE product = (%s)
                                             ORDER BY stocksessionID DESC LIMIT 1);

                            SET @secondLastDate = (SELECT sessionDate 
                                                   FROM stock WHERE product = (%s)
                                                   ORDER BY stocksessionID DESC LIMIT 1, 1);

                            SET @leadTime = (SELECT DATEDIFF(@lastDate, @secondLastDate));
                            SET @lastStockSessionID = (SELECT stocksessionID
                                                       FROM stock WHERE product = (%s)
                                                       ORDER BY stocksessionID DESC LIMIT 1);

                            UPDATE stock 
                            SET leadTime = (@leadTime)
                            WHERE stocksessionID = @lastStockSessionID;
                         """

self.query = self.cur.execute(self.calculateLeadTime, 
                              params=(self.productID.get(), self.productID.get(), self.productID.get()),
                              multi=True)
```

By the way, MySQL supports `JOIN` in `UPDATE` statements for a ***single*** statement. Run below with two parameters:

```sql
UPDATE stock s
INNER JOIN 
   (SELECT product, MAX(stocksessionID) AS MaxID
    FROM stock 
    WHERE product = %s
    GROUP BY product
   ) agg_id
ON s.stocksessionID = agg_id.MaxID

INNER JOIN
   (SELECT product, MAX(sessionDate) As MaxDate
    FROM stock 
    GROUP BY product) max_dt
ON max_dt.product = s.product

INNER JOIN
   (SELECT product, MAX(sessionDate) As SecMaxDate
    FROM stock 
    WHERE sessionDate < ( SELECT MAX(sessionDate)
                          FROM stock
                          WHERE product = %s )
    GROUP BY product
   ) sec_max_dt
ON max_dt.product = max_dt.product

SET leadTime =  DATEDIFF(MaxDate, SecMaxDate);
```

Comment: Thanks. I've tried both your methods however the leadTime column doesnt show the required values when selected in the MySql browser. Do you think this is related to the usage of mutli=True?

Comment: Do you still receive your original error? Undesired results may be a different SQL logic question. Without sample data of *stock* table, we cannot test either solution. How do you know the *required values*?  To debug, check individual subqueries or @variables return expected results. Check even parameter value.

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure, if this will work or counts even as multiple queries, because Multi = true is for multiple Resultsets from SELECTS.

You must add teh data for the %s

```
self.query = self.cur.execute(self.calculateLeadTime,('product','product','product') , multi=True)
```

Comment: I have tried both methods @Parfait has provided but neither work. Could you please elaborate on whether Multi=True is logical? Thanks.

Comment: I don't think that you need it at all, so try without it, but add the data as tupele as i showed in my answer  to you execute comand that works.  For more information on multi see https://overiq.com/mysql-connector-python-101/executing-queries-using-connector-python/